# Set ItemsSource to ContentPresenter.Content

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, itemssource, contentpresenter

I have tried this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="RowItemTemplate">
    <ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=BorderItemTemplate}" ItemsSource="ContentPresenter.Content">
    </ItemsControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

and it results in a stack overflow.  How to I set the ItemsSource of an ItemsControl to the content of the ContentPresenter?

Edit:

Changed `ItemsSource="ContentPresenter.Content"` to just `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` but I'm still getting a stack overflow.  The ItemsSource of the main ItemsControl is set to `new List<List<string>> { new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4" }, new List<string> { "1", "2", "3" }, new List<string> { "1", "2" }, new List<string> { "1" } };`  Here is a larger piece of my code:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="BorderItemTemplate">
        <Border RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Border.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-135"/>
            </Border.RenderTransform>
            <ContentPresenter/>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="RowItemTemplate">
        <ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=BorderItemTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<ItemsControl Name="comparisonGrid" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=RowItemTemplate}">
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: @SteveGreatrex The templated control's contentpresenter - I don't want a stack overflow

Comment: You aren't templating a control though (you can tell because you are using a `DataTemplate`, not a `ControlTemplate`).  Do you mean you want the `ItemsSource` to be the data that you are templating?

Comment: Hmmm, right.  I'm trying to template the data on another itemscontrol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to set the `ItemsSource` property to the data you are currently templating, you can use the following:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="RowItemTemplate">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    </ItemsControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

The binding is interpreted as "the value of `this.DataContext`", and `DataContext` is always set to the value that you are templating within a `DataTemplate`.

**Edit**

Looking at the OPs full code, I think that the problem is down to using the `ContentPresenter` within the `BorderItemTemplate`.  Assuming that the aim is to display the number to which it is bound, it should be replaced by the following:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="BorderItemTemplate">
    <Border RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Border.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="-135"/>
        </Border.RenderTransform>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I made that change, but I'm still getting a stack overflow.  I edited with a larger chunk of code.

Comment: Looking at your code, I think its more likely that its the `BorderItemTemplate` that is causing the problem - as a diagnostic step, can you comment out the `ContentPresenter` within *that* template?

Comment: That does seem to be the issue.  With what should I replace it?

Comment: That fixed it! (mostly) I just need to get things in the right place on the screen now.  Thanks for the help.